# React Conditional Rendering with states

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, state

I am working in a component where if i click on the `NavItem` i render an other list of elements

Function changing the state

```
handleClick() {
  this.setState({
    isActive: !this.state.isActive
  });
};
```

The Conditional Rendering

```
if (isActive) {
  SubList = <List hasIcons style="secondary"><ListItem><NavItem href={desktopUrl} title={title}><Icon name={name} />{title}</NavItem></ListItem></List>
}
```

The List NavItem and the `{{SubList}}`

```
<ListItem>
    <NavItem isActive href={desktopUrl} title={title} onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <Icon name={name} />
        {title}
    </NavItem>
    {SubList}
</ListItem>
```

Here the whole component

```
export default class SportNavItem extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { isActive: false };
    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({
      isActive: !this.state.isActive
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { title, desktopUrl, isActive, name } = this.props.data;
    // props.childItems; { title, name, isActive, url }

    // const itemId = `nav-${slugEn}`;
    const style = isActive ? "primary" : "default";

    let SubList = null;

    if (isActive) {
      SubList = (
        <List hasIcons style="secondary">
          <ListItem>
            <NavItem isActive href={desktopUrl} title={title}>
              <Icon name={name} />
              {title}
            </NavItem>
          </ListItem>
        </List>
      );
    }

    return (
      <List hasIcons style={style}>
        <ListItem>
          <NavItem isActive href={desktopUrl} title={title} onClick={this.handleClick}>
            <Icon name={name} />
            {title}
          </NavItem>
          {SubList}
        </ListItem>
      </List>
    );
  }
}
```

The Component exported

```
const sampleData = {
  title: 'Football',
  name: 'football',
  isActive: true,
  desktopUrl: '#'
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <SportNavItem data = { sampleData }/>
    </div>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

If i manually change the status `isActive` to `false` i can render the `SubList`. I can not achieve to handle the status `onClick` and i do not see error in the console. What is possibly wrong? Is there a better way?

Comment: You cannot `onClick` on custom component.
Wrap `NavItem` with a `div` that has the onClick method.

Comment: add it as an answer to accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Firstly** as @Jacob suggested, your variable `isActive` is a `state` and not a `prop`. You should use it like

```
const { title, desktopUrl, name  } = this.props.data;
const {isActive} = this.state;
```

**Secondly**, If `NavItem` is a custom component created by you then `onClick={this.handleClick}` will not set an `onClick` event on the `NavItem` rather than pass `onClick` as a prop to the `NavItem` component. In the `NavItem` component you can have an onClick event on a div that will in turn call the `onClick` function from the props resulting in `this.handleClick` being called. If you look at the `NavItem` component in `ReactBootstrap`. It has an `onClick` prop which will basically be doing the same thing as I suggested above

So technically you cannot have an `onClick` event on to any component. You can wrap the `NavItem` inside a div and then set an `onClick` event on that div

```
     <ListItem>
         <div onClick={this.handleClick}>   
            <NavItem isActive href={desktopUrl} title={title} >
                <Icon name={name} />
                {title}
            </NavItem>
            {SubList}
         </div>
    </ListItem>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to read `isActive` from `this.props.data`:

```
const { title, desktopUrl, isActive,  name  } = this.props.data;
```

...but `isActive` is in `this.state`. Change to this instead:

```
const { title, desktopUrl, name } = this.props.data;
const { isActive } = this.state;
```

Comment: yes this is the first mistake i am doing, not fixing though

Comment: What is `NavItem`? Does it have an `onClick` prop? You cannot add `onClick` to just anything.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `onClick` on custom component. Wrap NavItem with a div that has the `onClick` method.